# Simply a FLOOR equation

Tags: function, math, floor-division

I have a long equation that I want to simplify but I am out of ideas how to.

> 4*(floor((15-11*x-floor(x/19)+floor(x%)-floor(x%/4)-floor((floor(x%)+1-floor((floor(x%)+8)/25))/3))/30)-floor((15-11*x-floor(x/19))/30))+floor((floor((floor(x%)+1-floor((floor(x%)+8)/25))/3)+3+3*x-floor(x/4)+floor(x/19)+2*floor(0.5-11/30*x-floor(x/19)/30+(floor(x%)-floor(x%/4)-floor((floor(x%)+1-floor((floor(x%)+8)/25))/3))/30))/7)-floor((5+3*x-floor(x/4)+floor(x/19)+2*floor(0.5-11/30*x-floor(x/19)/30))/7)+floor((13-54/11*x-2*floor(x/4)-8/11*floor(x/19)+floor((floor(x%)+1-floor((floor(x%)+8)/25))/3)+floor(x%)-3*floor(x%/4)-26*floor((15-11*x-floor(x/19)+floor(x%)-floor(x%/4)-floor((floor(x%)+1-floor((floor(x%)+8)/25))/3))/30)-14*floor((1+floor((floor(x%)+1-floor((floor(x%)+8)/25))/3)+3*x-floor(x/4)+floor(x/19)+2*floor((15-11*x-floor(x/19)+floor(x%)-floor(x%/4)-floor((floor(x%)+1-floor((floor(x%)+8)/25))/3))/30))/7))/41)

I only want to use floor function.

x here is a positive integer (x>1582) and x% is x divided by 100.

Thank you in advance

Comment: the operations are float or integer? may be plotting a graph on usable range of `x` would tell you more ... you can always use LUT+interpolation or approximation polynomial or curve fitting but if you want to algebraically correct result without accuracy loss then only way is algebra which is a math problem not suitable for this site. You can try Derive for windows or any other math equation solver to simplify this madness.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simplify `floor(x+y)` for fractional x and y, but if you know that x is an integer, then `floor(x+y) = x + floor(y)`

You can also simplify `floor(floor(x/a)/b)` over integers

Indeed, let's write the Euclidean divisions for positive integers `x = b * (a*y+c) + d` with `c < a` and `d < b`

We have `x = a*b * y + (b*c+d)`

Over the integers we can write `c <= a - 1`, thus `b*c <= (a-1)*b`.

And then using other inequality `d < b` => `b*c+d < (a-1)*b+b`, thus `b*c+d < a*b`.

Thus `floor(floor(x/a)/b) = floor( x/(a*b) )` over positive integers.

What you could do is to write the bounds of expressions like:

```
floor(a/c)+floor(b/c) <= floor((a+b)/c) <= floor(a/b)+floor(b/c)+1
```

then apply simplifications rules on the bounds